# psycopg2 erroring out when reading dates out of range

Tags: python, timestamp, psycopg2

I get

> ValueError: year is out of range

When my `psycopg2` **cursor.fetchall** encounters a date value with a weird year, such as 0001.

Is there any way to make psycopg2 compatible with any year and avoid this exception?

Answer (score 4):

extending to piro's answer

```
DATE2STR = psycopg2.extensions.new_type(
    psycopg2.extensions.DATE.values,
    'DATE2STR',
    lambda value, curs:
        str(value) if value is not None else None)

psycopg2.extensions.register_type(DATE2STR)
```

Comment: I can't even begin to tell you how much headache this little workaround saved me. Upvoted, but if I could upvote a thouusand I would have done so. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own typecaster and return date.min if the year is less than what python supports. See [this faq](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/faq.html#faq-float) (about returning `float` instead of `Decimal` for `numeric` data) and use it as a starting point to customize it for your data type and your requirements.